# How to adjust the order of file sorting?

Tags: matlab, sorting, directory

I am trying to evalute my Lab data, what are represtned into TXT files then plot the conntents of data.

```
      dataDirectory = 'files location  ';
      allFilesDir = dir(fullfile(dataDirectory , '*.txt'));
      allFN = {allFilesDir.name};

      result = [];

      for n = 1:length(allFN)
      measNr(n) = str2double(regexprep(allFN{n},'**.txt',''));

      myFN = (fullfile(dataDirectory, allFN{n}));
      auxv =try1(myFN);
      result(n,:) = mean(auxv.data);
      end
```

This code is workin but into wrong order arrangemnt the TXT files (0,1,11,12,13,14 .....)
which give me wrong plot data. I used

```
       plot(measNr,resultMG(1:35,2),'x');
```

but i read that i can use sort_nat in this way but it did not work for me .

```
       % [~, order] = sort_nat({result});
       % result = result(order);
```

and I got this error messge

```
       :??? Undefined function or method 'sort_nat' for input arguments of type
       'cell'.:
```

any suggestion???

Answer (score 0):

As the error message clearly suggests, `sort_nat` is not a builtin function.
It is a function available on the file exchange:

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10959-sortnat-natural-order-sort

Comment: thx for note. so how to use this file and is my code into right way to work with this function ?

Comment: Download the file from the File Exchange and put it somewhere on your MATLAB path. Check MATLAB can find it by typing `which -all sort_nat` which should return you the path to `sort_nat.m`.